# Cosa significa "rispianare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto:

> Tossí a scoppi, a schianti, con stelle e
>   lampi rossi e gialli nel cielo nero degli occhi serrati, sussultando sul terreno come un serpe trafitto. Poi, con le
>   labbra sporche di fango, **rispianò** gli occhi al ponte. I
>   soldati non avevano sentito, fumavano e scorrevano con
>   gli occhi ogni strato della collina piramidale.

Il personaggio che svolge questa azione è Milton, il protagonista del romanzo.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "rispianò gli occhi al ponte" nel brano precedente. Ho cercato il vocabolo "rispianare" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che significa "spianare di nuovo o meglio", ma questa definizione non sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Di solito si può *spianare un'arma*, cioè metterla in posizione di tiro.

Qui Fenoglio ne dà un'estensione un po' stiracchiata, secondo me, ma l'uso di parole in sensi leggermente diversi dal solito è comune nella letteratura: Milton pose di nuovo gli occhi in modo da poter tenere sotto tiro il ponte.

Answer (score 1):

Con l'espressione *rispianò gli occhi al ponte* Fenoglio dice due azioni, quasi contemporanee. Dice che Milton riaprì gli occhi che prima erano serrati, li distese cioè dopo il momento di tensione, e li volse verso il ponte. Con il solo verbo *rispianare* ci dice che il momento della tosse, violento (come dicono le parole usate: scoppi, schianti, lampi, sussultando), si placa. In più, Milton aveva dovuto nascondere il colpo di tosse per non farsi sentire dai soldati, e si accorge che ci è riuscito.

Comment: E perché avrebbe questo significato? Forse quello che si spiana sono le palpebre?

Comment: È come quando si dice "spianare la fronte". Per quanto riguarda il "tornare a guardare il ponte", funziona la proposta di @egreg di tenere presente il significato di "spianare un'arma". Credo comunque, come dicevo, che questo verbo dica più cose insieme (è uno dei motivi per cui amo molto Fenoglio).